# how to also update user attribute in AD for child domains in the same domain controller

Tags: powershell

I do have a test AD with two child domains runing on the same domain controller. i created a script to update user manager attribute for each user in each domain(root domain and the two childomain) however, my script is failing. the script works when i only write it to update one domain at a time but it does not work for mulitple domains. The users are imported from CSV file.
Seems my if statements are not well written for the rest of the other domains.

## Import the Active Directory module

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
```

## Define the path to the CSV file

```
$csvPath = "C:\temp\ADscriptfileAll3domains-Test1.csv"
```

## Read the CSV file

```
$users = Import-Csv -Path $csvPath# Loop through each user in the CSV

foreach ($user in $users) {
# Extract the user details from the CSV
$userPrincipalName = $user.userPrincipalName
$manager = $user.manager

# Check if the user exists in Active Directory for root domain(serverdc.testab.com)
$existingUser = Get-ADUser -Filter "userPrincipalName -eq '$userPrincipalName'"
$existingUser2 = Get-ADUser -Filter "userPrincipalName -eq '$userPrincipalName'" -Server 'serverdc.child1.testab.com'
$existingUser3 = Get-ADUser -Filter "userPrincipalName -eq '$userPrincipalName'" -Server 'serverdc.child2.testab.com'


 if ($existingUser) {
    # Update the user details in Active Directory for root domain
    Set-ADUser -Identity $existingUser -manager $manager
    }

 if ($existingUser2) {
    # Update the user details in Active Directory for child domain 1
    Set-ADUser -Identity $existingUser2 -manager $manager
    }
 if ($existingUser3) {
    # Update the user details in Active Directory for users in child domain 2
    Set-ADUser -Identity $existingUser3 -manager $manager
    }





  Write-Host "User '$manager' updated."
} else {
  Write-Host "User '$manager' not found. Skipping update."
    }
```

Comment: You're missing `-Server` in the `Set-ADUser` statements ;)

Comment: Hello @SantiagoSquarzon thanks for the input . the absences of the -server was intetntion. the first code line is doing work on the root domain. even if you do not put that server it would run.